# QThread creation and exchanging data over slots

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is my thread header file:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QString>
#include "typedef.h"

class ImgProcess : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImgProcess(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

    bool Stop;
    ImageInfo iInf;

signals:
    void valueChanged(int);
    void NewFile(QString FileName, MyCustomStruct* MetaData);

public slots:

private slots:

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyCustomStruct);
```

and this is code I use to create 10 threads from this class (above header file is `ImgProcess.h`)

```
void CreateThreads()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomStruct>("MyCustomStruct");
    QList<QThread*> ThreadList;
    for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        QThread* thread = new QThread;
        ImgProcess *PrcThread = new ImgProcess(this);
        PrcThread->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(PrcThread, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this, SLOT(onValueChanged(int)));
        connect(PrcThread, SIGNAL(NewFile(QString,MyCustomStruct*)),this, SLOT(NewFile(QString,MyCustomStruct*)));
        PrcThread->start();
        ThreadList.push_back(thread);
    }
}
```

The `valuChanged` signal/slot works well, I'm able to send integer from threads to thread creator class, I even tried `QString` and I was able to send `QString` from thread to creator.

Now I want to exchange `MyCustomStruct` which does have several `int`, `Qstring`, `char`, `doubles`, another struct embedded, etc. Now it doesn't work, I tried to do `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`, but no luck. So what am I missing?

In main thread when I try to read `MetaData->DateTime();` I get access denied error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Call qRegisterMetaType() to make custom types available to non-template based functions, such as the queued signal and slot connections. Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor can be registered.

You should call this for example in your CreathThreads() function:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomStruct>("MyCustomStruct");
```

Also you should declare MyCustomStruct as a class and prepare a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor for it.

Comment: Be sure that MyCustomStruct is a class and has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor.

Comment: MyCustomStruct is a struct, not a class, just want to pass it as parameter via signal/slot